# Compile list of words from list of files

Tags: awk, sed, text, tr

How would one take on this task?

I've tried to do it with tr, and come up with this (with help of other similar question):

`tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' < long_concatenated_file`

but.. Its a bit of a problem. `:alnum:` is only list of characters & numbers. I've tried to mitigate that after reading `man`:

`tr -c '[:alnum:=-=]' '[\n*]' < long_concatenated_file`

which should have included words with dashes in them into list of things to be replaced, but no, it didn't for some reason.

What would be the correct way of taking on this task?

For clarity, end-goal of it is to apply `sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` to it, to identify most used strings in project, so I could convert them to convenient constants; if my approach to the problem is completely nonsensical and I should approach it some other way, please suggest something.

Comment: Some sample (representative!) input and output would help.

Comment: Are your files unicode? Can you have characters like `—` or `é` or  fancy quotes etc? What language are these words in? What format are the files in? Many words per line?

Comment: Are you trying to get frequencies of words as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552803/how-to-create-a-frequency-list-of-every-word-in-a-file ?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to replace all non-word characters (alphanumerics) with newlines, and then you try to include `-` in the set of non-word characters.

To do that with `tr` (here, I've also included `'` as a valid word character, and I use `-s` to remove consecutive newlines in the output):

```
tr -s -c "[:alnum:]-'" '\n'
```

or, using the equivalence class `[=-=]` as you seem to want to do:

```
tr -s -c "[:alnum:][=-=]'" '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kusalandra, thanks for answer, but it was a bit not what I wanted to do. My aim was to print every word that consists of :alnum: set or '-' character on separate line.

Resulting sequence is creating a new class, ie:

`cat longfile | tr -c '[[:alnum:]-]' '[\n*]'`

does what I wanted to do.

example:

`$echo aaa-abc asdasd asswdwew | tr -c '[[:alnum:]-]' '[\n*]'

aaa-abc
asdasd
asswdwew`